# Alter table INT value from signed to unsigned execution

Tags: mysql, int

I have a table with the primary key of max signed `INT` hit, `2147483647`

Imagine I want to switch it to unsigned, and there are no negative values in the table since it is a primary key, because Im under the current belief that it is the fastest way to get the table going again.

Should the `ALTER TABLE` statement to switch it to an unsigned `INT` be a relatively quick process, since the values of the ids shouldn't change? What about locking?

Comment: You can change to signed to unsigned state and it will not effect on any of your data.

Comment: It doesn't have to update each row sort of quick.

Comment: I'd like to know more about how that works or what scenarios would force it to change it possibly. An unsigned positive value is the same as a positive signed value I would've thought, so the alter table would just make negative values impossible to insert.

Comment: The table takes 4 hours to run the alter table statement were we change from signed to unsigned, any help would be sweet.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Latest versions enable you to specify `ALGORITHM=INPLACE LOCK=NONE` on your `ALTER TABLE` statement, which will very quickly update column metadata without copying the table data.

Comment: @eggyal only if the specific change can be done without copying. Otherwise the command with fail with an error. Mysql documentation does not list changing the column type as change that can be done in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mysql documentation on [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) command describes quite in a detailed manner under "Storage, Performance, and Concurrency Considerations" section which changes can be done quickly, without table copy and index rebuild, and what locks mysql will apply during the course of the command. Changing the column type is unfortunately not listed as something that can be done in place (of course, read the documentation corresponding to your mysql version, I just linked the newest one).

> For some operations, an in-place ALTER TABLE is possible that does not
>   require a temporary table:
>
> For ALTER TABLE tbl_name RENAME TO new_tbl_name without any other options, MySQL simply renames any files that correspond to the table
>   tbl_name without making a copy. (You can also use the RENAME TABLE
>   statement to rename tables. See Section 13.1.28, “RENAME TABLE
>   Syntax”.) Any privileges granted specifically for the renamed table
>   are not migrated to the new name. They must be changed manually.
>
> Alterations that modify only table metadata and not table data are immediate because the server only needs to alter the table .frm file,
>   not touch table contents. The following changes are fast alterations
>   that can be made this way:
>
> - Renaming a column.
> - Changing the default value of a column.
> - Changing the definition of an ENUM or SET column by adding new enumeration or set members to the end of the list of valid member
>     values, as long as the storage size of the data type does not change.
>     For example, adding a member to a SET column that has 8 members
>     changes the required storage per value from 1 byte to 2 bytes; this
>     will require a table copy. Adding members in the middle of the list
>     causes renumbering of existing members, which requires a table copy.
> - ALTER TABLE with DISCARD ... PARTITION ... TABLESPACE or IMPORT ... PARTITION ... TABLESPACE do not create any temporary tables or
>     temporary partition files.
> - ALTER TABLE with ADD PARTITION, DROP PARTITION, COALESCE PARTITION, REBUILD PARTITION, or REORGANIZE PARTITION does not create
>     any temporary tables (except when used with NDB tables); however,
>     these operations can and do create temporary partition files.
> - ADD or DROP operations for RANGE or LIST partitions are immediate operations or nearly so. ADD or COALESCE operations for HASH or KEY
>     partitions copy data between all partitions, unless LINEAR HASH or
>     LINEAR KEY was used; this is effectively the same as creating a new
>     table, although the ADD or COALESCE operation is performed partition
>     by partition. REORGANIZE operations copy only changed partitions and
>     do not touch unchanged ones.
> - Renaming an index.
> - Adding or dropping an index, for InnoDB.

Locking:

> While ALTER TABLE is executing, the original table is readable by
>   other sessions (with the exception noted shortly). Updates and writes
>   to the table that begin after the ALTER TABLE operation begins are
>   stalled until the new table is ready, then are automatically
>   redirected to the new table without any failed updates. The temporary
>   copy of the original table is created in the database directory of the
>   new table. This can differ from the database directory of the original
>   table for ALTER TABLE operations that rename the table to a different
>   database.
>
> The exception referred to earlier is that ALTER TABLE blocks reads
>   (not just writes) at the point where it is ready to install a new
>   version of the table .frm file, discard the old file, and clear
>   outdated table structures from the table and table definition caches.
>   At this point, it must acquire an exclusive lock. To do so, it waits
>   for current readers to finish, and blocks new reads (and writes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer : Does switching from unsigned to signed int necessarily change the type?

Comment: It changes the allowable number range, so yes, it is a change in data type. **You** know that there are no values in the data that are affected, but mysql does not know that. Furthermore, I'm not sure how the index records are affected. However, you can try to force mysql to use an inplace change as described by @eggyal in a comment. You get an error message if that is not supported. Trying it out on a test table cannot hurt you.